# How to push an element into a typescript array

Tags: angular, typescript

I made an array of type dataRows which is an interface

```
dataArray: Array<dataRows>;
```

then in a function I pushed a dataRows object into it

```
this.dataArray.push(row)
```

so why do I get Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in the console?

Comment: The array mus tbe initialized before accessing it's methods/properties: `dataArray: Array<dataRows> = [];`.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely getting the error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` because your `dataArray` hasn't been defined yet, and is thus `undefined` - a blank object with no methods.

You need to initialise it with an empty array, like:

```
dataArray: Array<dataRows> = [];
```

to then be able to use the `.push` method to append your `row` to it.